# How to pass response values to Java API from Karate

Tags: web-services, testing, automation, karate

How can I pass values from Karate API to Java class?

As mentioned in the documentation, I used the following code snippet to get the response from Java API. But its returning the response with un-formatted JSON content.

```
Map<String, Object> result = CucumberRunner.runClasspathFeature("demo/java/from-java.feature", args, true);
```

And then, I used the following script to print the response.

```
for(Map.Entry<String , Object> entry: getMbrWksMembershipDetailsResponse.entrySet())
{
    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("response"))
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

It shows like,

```
{soap:Envelope={_={soap:Body={ns1:getMbrWksMembershipDetailsResponse={_={ns4:WksMembershipSummaryResponse={_={ns2:customerSummary={ns2:address={ns2:city=SOUTH CHESTERFIELD, ns2:country=USA, ns2:isoCountryCode=US, ns2:line1=9998, N. MICHIGAN ROAD., ns2:postalCode=23834, ns2:state=VA}, ns2:allowPasswordChange=true, ns2:arpMember=false, ns2:brandCode=RCI, ns2:brandId=1, ns2:companyCode=RCI, ns2:eliteMemberRewardStatus=false, ns2:eliteRewardStatus=true, ns2:europePointsClubMember=false, ns2:firstName=FRANK, ns2:homePhone=804/733-3004, ns2:isoCurrencyCode=USD, ns2:isoLanguageCode=EN, ns2:language=EN, ns2:lastName=BROWNING B, ns2:locale=en_US, ns2:memberDeveloperRenewed=false, ns2:memberEnrolledDate=2009-10-26T00:00:00-04:00, ns2:memberEnrolledForDirectDebit=false, ns2:memberEnrolledForPltDirectDebit=false, ns2:memberStatus=A, ns2:middleName=B, ns2:msgTranslationLanguageCode=EN, ns2:officePhone=0/-0, ns2:pointsCurrencyCode=0......
```

So it's little difficult to split the data based on the fields / tags from **Map**.

Please suggest what is the best option to get the values field wize / tag wise from Java API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, XML is internally held as a strange `Map` structure, refer to the section on [type-conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion) to understand more.

You have a simple way to do this. Just define a new variable that is the `response` converted to a string.

```
* xmlstring responseXml = response
```

After this you just need to get the `responseXml` out of the `Map` returned by the Java API which will be a string.

Note: don't use the Java API unless you are *really* trying to mix Karate with something else. The whole point of Karate is to avoid using Java for testing JSON and XML web-services.

Comment: Hi, I used like this    * def xmlVar = response
   * def APIHelperClass = Java.type('com.org.utilities.APIHelperClass')
   * def result = APIHelperClass.getResponse(xmlVar)
   * print 'Result :', result ---------- but the result is the same of above format.... :(

Comment: yes of course. read my answer carefully. do you see ‘def’ anywhere ?